# Entity framework string to guid

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Hi my domain models use string as there Ids.

```
public class TeamModel
{
    public string TeamId { get; set; }
    public string TeamName { get; set; }
}
```

Where as my entities use a Guid as there Ids

```
     public class Team
     {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public Guid TeamId { get; set; }
        public string TeamName { get; set; }
     }
```

Now im using automapper to map models to entities, just wondering if there is a data annotation that would allow me to set my TeamId as a string in the entity, but it then auto formats to a guid and generates the new guid before storing in the database

EDIT

The reason for string as Id in the domain model is because this is a research project with sql and mongoDb

my mongoDb entity looks like this

```
public class Team
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string TeamId { get; set; }
    public string TeamName
}
```

So my domain will either pass a domain model to sql or mongo. Mongo converts string to ObjectId fine, I just need EF to be able to do something similar so I can use generic models in domain

Comment: Why is your TeamId of type string in the model? Can't you make it of type Guid and use the Guid.ToString()-method when necessary?

Comment: In that case I would write a custom mapping in Automapper to map the properties. I don't think this can be auto-magically done using data-annotations.

Answer (score 0):

Not I am aware of. Suggest (if you are really required to have it of string type in your model) to make additional properties that will convert to string\guid in a [set and get accessors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa287786(v=vs.71).aspx).